# In Maven2, is there a way to scope a dependency to "package only" and keep it off the test classpath?

Tags: java, maven-2, dependencies

**Setup**
I'm packaging a WAR with a number of legacy jar dependencies in it (for the sake of keeping this simple, they can not possibly be altered or excluded from the deployed WAR).

**Issue**
Including either or both of two of these jars will cause inexorable errors at test-time. If I exclude the dependencies altogether, the tests pass happily, but the WAR will lack real-world runtime classes it needs.

**Hope** 
Maven2 offers compile, test, runtime, system, and provided scopes. Sadly, none of these will be [included in the assembly but kept off the test classpath](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Dependency+Scopes). My hope is that I'm missing some obvious way to handle this case entirely within the dependency management feature.

**Fear**
I'll have to use the assembly plugin to copy these problem jars into the target. I don't want to have to skirt the dependency management system to copy jars in the clear into the target, as I don't want to manage these jars outside the internal repository.

Thoughts? Alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it figures that I'd come across a potential solution to this moments after posting a question. It appears that the copy goal of the dependency plugin may handle this. Going to try this out now: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html

Edit: Turns out that this worked fine for my needs, snippet below:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <artifactItems>
            <artifactItem>
                <groupId>group</groupId>
                <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
                <version>version</version>
                <type>jar</type>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/lib</outputDirectory>
            </artifactItem>
        </artifactItems>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Break the test classes out of the jar file into a separate jar which is only for tests, and add an exclusion to the dependency on the jar with the legacy dependencies.